# ESLint running in terminal but doesn't pick up error

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I'm following a tutorial using `create-react-app` and configuring ESLint.

I already installed ESLint globally, I have a `.eslintrc.json` file in the root folder and `.vscode/settings.json`

### Current problem:

- After configuring, ESLint Output runs normally but didn't pick up any error from my code.
- Ex: When I hover over `.textContent`, it supposed to have a suggestion to use `.toHaveTextContent` instead:
  [image: There should be a suggestion pop-up from ESLint here]
- I tried restarting VSCode, uninstalling ESLint extension and installing it again but still - doesn't work and no error in the Output.

### Screenshots & Code:

**File tree:**

[image]

**ESLint Output:**
[image]

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "testing-library",
    "jest-dom"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:testing-library/react"
  ]
}
```

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "color-button",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I haven't added `"plugin:jest-dom/recommended"` rule in my `.eslintrc.json` file.

That's why it didn't pick up error with `jest-dom`'s syntax :)

**Fixed this:**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "testing-library",
    "jest-dom"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:testing-library/react",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended"
  ]
}
```

[image]